# Error in regards to 'ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException' and more?

Tags: java

I cant seem to figure out what is causing this following error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at Bank.main(Bank.java:42) <--- this line is referring to the code line that starts as  "banklist.add(new Bank(values[0]...."

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
    {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("Bank Data.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
        List<Bank> banklist = new ArrayList<Bank>();
       try { 
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
            String[] values = line.split("/t"); // Split on "tab"

            banklist.add(new Bank(values[0], Integer.parseInt(values[1]),Integer.parseInt(values[2]),Integer.parseInt(values[3]),Integer.parseInt(values[4]), values[5])); // Create a new Player object with the values extract and add it to the list
```

Comment: Is it possible that the last line of input is ""? I.e. there is a stray \n at the end of the file?

Comment: Have you considered splitting apart that megaline into separate assignments to temps so you can debug it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have split on `/t` rather than `\t`. Note backslash rather than forward slash.

Since your lines probably don't contain any `/t` sequences, you don't get all the words your code expects.

Comment: Valid point and after fixing this error it still is giving me the error.

Comment: Then you should probably see Akhilesh's answer. Inspect the results from splitting properly and see in what way they differ from how you'd expect them to look. Clearly, you are getting less words than you expect, but the reason can't be known without knowing the input.

Comment: After checking out the TXT file i noticed that the TABS were not properly in place.i.e there were more than one tab between columns. after fixing this the code works. Thanks you all for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Most possible explanation is that in your file, there are lines which does not have tab. Maybe last line is empty.

Possible solution may be to do a defensive programming and check the length of array before directly indexing it as array[1].

Answer (score 0):

You have used Wrong expression.

Find below Solution..

```
       while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            String regexp = "[\\s,;\\t]+";
            String[] values = line.split(regexp);

            banklist.add(new Bank(values[0],
                    Integer.parseInt(values[1]),
                    values[2],
                    values[3],
                    Integer.parseInt(values[4]),
                    values[5])
            );



        }
```